# fetch images and display on web page with the help of search bar

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I can be able to display images from the database but how to search the particular image and display into web page using search bar , what will be the best approach, can someone help me out with this code , because I am basic learner of `PHP` ..

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("display_images");
    $res=mysql_query("select *from table1");
    echo "<table>";

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";?> <img src="<?php echo $row["images1"];?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>"; echo $row["name"]; echo"</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>


    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and removed library now. Please move towards `PHP7` along with `mysqli_*` or `PDO` library for database handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said `mysql_*` is deprecated and removed library now, I am going to give you a sample example of `mysqli_*`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="image_name" placeholder="type a name and hit submit button to see particular image">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <table>
        <?php

        $connection = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "display_images" ) or die( mysqli_connect_error() );

        $query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
        if( !empty( $_POST['image_name'] ) ){
            $image_name = $_POST['image_name'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE images1 LIKE %$image_name%"; 
            //you can do $image_name% or %$image_name based on your requirement
        }
        $result = mysqli_query( $connection, $query ) or die( mysqli_error( $connection ) );

        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $res ) ){ 
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="<?php echo $row["images1"];?>" height="100" width="100"> 
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $row["name"];?></td>

            </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </table>
</body>
```

***Note:*** Use prepared statement to prevent from SQL INJECTION

Reference:-

[mysqli::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this example code

```
<table>
    <?php
    $db_connect = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "display_images" ) or die( "Database not connected!" );
    $select_data = mysqli_query( $db_connect, "SELECT * FROM table1 ") or die( mysqli_error( $db_connect ) );
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $select_data) ){ 
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="<?php echo $row["images1"];?>" height="100" width="100"> 
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $row["name"];?></td>
        </tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

**Or try it**

```
<?php
$view="";
$db_connect = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "display_images" ) or die( "Database not connected!" );
$select_data = mysqli_query( $db_connect, "SELECT * FROM table1 ") or die( mysqli_error( $db_connect ) );
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $select_data) ){
    $view=$view.'<table>';
    $view=$view.'<tr>';
    $view=$view.'<td>';
    $view=$view.'<img src=images/'.$row["images1"].' style="height:100px;width:100px">';
    $view=$view.'</td>';
    $view=$view.'<td>'.$row["name"].'</td>';
    $view=$view.'</tr>';
    $view=$view.'</table>';
}
echo $view;
```

Comment: You didn't answer OP's actual question:- `but how to search the particular image and display into web page using search bar `